# combining list of lists from values of dictionary into list of tuple in single expression python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
  myDict = {'a' : [[1,2], [3,4]], 'b':[[5,6],[7,8]]}
```

From this above dictionary I want to construct a single list of tuples as follows:

```
  [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)]
```

I can achieve this with following piece of code:

```
  l=[]
  for _, v in myDict.items():
     for i in v:
       l.append(tuple(i))
```

Can I do the same using single expression ?

Comment: `[tuple(i) for v in myDict.values() for i in v]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
list(map(tuple, (e for l in myDict.values() for e in l)))
```

you could flatten `myDict.values()` using [more_itertools.flatten](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.flatten):

```
from more_itertools import flatten

list(map(tuple, flatten(myDict.values())))
```

also, you could use a list comprehension:

```
[tuple(e) for e in flatten(myDict.values())]
```

output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Comment: the order is guaranteed for python version >= 3.6, and he is using python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
list(map(tuple,itertools.chain.from_iterable(myDict.values())))
# [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```